# How to make the loop working without keep increment the index nonstop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the loop flag is set to true it's continuing moving between the waypoints nonsotp.

The problem is when the flag loop is set to false then it stop at the last waypoint but then also give exception : ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The index is keep raising in the Move function.
I'm not sure how to solve it when the loop flag is false.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public List<Transform> positions;
    public bool loop = true;

    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            transform.position = positions[index].position;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                                positions[index].position,
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positions[index].position);
        if (distance < 0.01f)
        {
            positions[index].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            index += 1;
        }

        if (index == positions.Count && loop)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have `if (index == positions.Count) {index = 0; go = loop;}`? By the way, you don't need `if (go == true)`, you can just have `if (go)`

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks. working.

Comment: @Ruzihm if I want to change the loop so it will continue from the last waypoint ? now if the loop is false it stop in the last waypoint but if I set it to true it's not moving to the first waypoint just stay at the last one. I want to be able to change the loop flag in the end or in the middle and that it will affect when reaching the last waypoint.

Comment: just because you set loop to true, that doesn't always mean you want the movement to resume. You have to set `go=true` if you want it to resume once it has stopped.

Comment: @Ruzihm not to resume or pause for that I use the go flag.  I mean to decide if to loop when the transform reach the last waypoint or to stop at the last waypoint.  if I change the loop in the middle it should then decide if to loop or not at the last waypoint not to resume or pause.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what that comment means. It might help if you ask another question and include more information about the new problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to stop entering `Move` at the end of your waypoint sequence depending on if `loop` is disabled or not:

```
if (index == positions.Count) 
{
    index = 0; 
    go = loop;
}
```